# command work in command prompt but not in batch file

Tags: command-line, batch-file, smtp, sendmail

I am trying to send out email attachment periodically from a batch script using this command line client

http://caspian.dotconf.net/menu/Software/SendEmail

the command for it is pretty straightforward

```
sendEmail -t abc@gmail.com -u hellp -f abd@nus.edu.sg -m world -s smtp.nus.edu.sg -xu nusstu\a123456 -xp helloworld! -a C:\Users\ll\Desktop\Quotes.docx
```

The strange thing is if I type that line in command prompt, it works perfectly fine. I can 
receive the email with attachment.

However, when I put it into a batch script, like

```
:email
sendEmail -t abc@gmail.com -u hellp -f abd@nus.edu.sg -m world -s smtp.nus.edu.sg -xu       nusstu\a123456 -xp helloworld! -a C:\Users\ll\Desktop\Quotes.docx
goto:eof
```

and I call this subroutine in my batch file, the output says

```
SMTP:AUTH authentication to smtp.nus.edu.sg:25 failed.
```

I checked. no typo, Could someone help me what is the difference? why the same command works in command line but cause trouble in a script file?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using delayed expansion?

Comment: Yes, You saved my day! I did put that at the beginning, once deleted, problem solved! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're censoring your batch too much.

Try running the following:

```
@ECHO OFF

setlocal
echo sendEmail -t abc@gmail.com -u hellp -f abd@nus.edu.sg -m world -s smtp.nus.edu.sg -xu nusstu\a123456 -xp helloworld! -a C:\Users\ll\Desktop\Quotes.docx
endlocal

SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
echo sendEmail -t abc@gmail.com -u hellp -f abd@nus.edu.sg -m world -s smtp.nus.edu.sg -xu nusstu\a123456 -xp helloworld! -a C:\Users\ll\Desktop\Quotes.docx
echo sendEmail -t abc@gmail.com -u hellp -f abd@nus.edu.sg -m world -s smtp.nus.edu.sg -xu  nusstu\a123456 -xp helloworld^^! -a C:\Users\ll\Desktop\Quotes.docx
goto:eof
```

Because your password contains `!`, batch interprets that as a variable-name if DELAYEDEXPANSION is invoked. Since the variablename isn't set, it's replaced by [nothing] and `sendtoemail` believes that your password is `helloworld\Users\ll\Desktop\Quotes.docx` - hence the error message.

Comment: Thanks for answering still, the problem is that I used  delayed expansion. Once deleted, everything is fine！